# Как узнать id канала в телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот отправляет сообщение написавшему пользователю:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hey user')
```

Эта функция прекрасно работает при личной переписке с ботом. Бота добавил в свой канал, сделал админом. На сообщения не реагирует. Как сделать, чтобы бот отвечал в других каналах? или как узнать id этих самых каналов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI), можно воспользоваться отладкой:

```
import logging
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

- добавьте бота в канал
- назначьте его администратором
- отправьте в канал сообщение, например `/start`

в консоли вы должны увидеть примерно следующее:

> 2020-05-04 20:57:03,847 (apihelper.py:55 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":661653078,\n"channel_post":{"message_id":4276,"chat":{"id":-100...413,"title":"%name channel%","type":"channel"},"date":1588615023,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}]}''"

где `id: -100...413` и есть id канала

Comment: спасибо. помогло а не подскажите как добавить, чтобы бот в самом канале считывал сообщения?

Comment: добавил еще один ответ. если первый ответ оказался полезным, пожалуйста отметьте его как решение. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

для того чтобы реагировать на посты из каналов используйте `@bot.channel_post_handler()`

пример:

```
@bot.channel_post_handler()
def channel(message):
    if message.chat.id == %ваш id канала%:  # если бот в нескольких каналах, можно разделять действия по id
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ответ на пост в канале')
```